# Vim white background

Tags: vim, neovim

I have 1 problem in vim. I installed solarized theme in iterm and vim. But everytime time when I launch vim I have white background.

[image]

But after I type

```
set background=dark
```

or

```
set background=light
```

I got what I want.

[image]

What the problem can it be?
My [.vimrc](https://github.com/Dzhaba/dotfiles/blob/master/vimrc)

Comment: This is off-topic, but, don't neobundle, vundle and vim-plug all basically do the same thing? Why are you using all 3?

Comment: I didn't realize it when i only started using vim, but know i removed 2 of them ) Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Wray Zheng said the problem probably is caused by some plugin. You have to comment/uncomment each plugin and see what will happen or listen to the `SourcePre` event and detect which script changes the `background` option.

```
let g:log = []

function! Log()
    call add(g:log, [&background, expand("<amatch>")])
endfunction

autocmd SourcePre * call Log()
```

Then just `:echo g:log`.

Comment: Found it ! It was csapprox. Thx for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try moving

```
set background=dark
```

to the below of

```
colorscheme solarized
```

in your `.vimrc` file.

Comment: Probably there are some plugin or script which is loaded after the .vimrc and has the background set. Use `:scriptnames` to check what scripts are loaded and which may be responsible for that.